# How to minimize my nasty function using scipy.minimize?

Tags: optimization, scipy, minimize

I am trying to minimize a function using scipy.minimize. The columns of the text file imported are integers. The codes work except the last two lines.

```
from sympy.abc import *
import sympy as s
import numpy as n
from scipy.optimize import minimize
H0,mo,e,z,g = s.symbols('H0 mo e z g')
dz = ((1+z)/H0)*(s.integrate(s.nsimplify((6/H0)/(g+(6-g)*(1+z)**3),z),z)).doit()
mt = 5*s.log(10**(5)*dz)+25
c1 = ((mt-mo)**2)/e**2
c2 = s.lambdify((H0,g,z,mo,e),c1,"numpy")
c3 = n.vectorize(c2)
data = n.genfromtxt('data_file_580.txt',usecols=[1,2,3])
z = data[:,[0]]
mo = data[:,[1]]
e = data[:,[2]]
c4 = c3(z,mo,e,g,H0)
c5 = n.sum(c4)
def f(c5):
    H0,g=c5
    return c5
bnds = ((65,80),(4,6))
minimize(f,(65,4),bounds=bnds)
```

Getting an error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

If i use `def f(H0,g)` instead of `def f(c5)` in line 17, throwing an error

```
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'g'
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Are you aware that the argument called `c5` shadows the global name `c5`? So the function `f` returns the parameter vector, which is certainly wrong and causes the `ValueError`. What is this code supposed to do anyway? I strongly suspect some of the lines should actually go inside the body of `f` and there may be other issues as well...

Comment: anyway, what could i do ?

Comment: I don't know. The code does not make sense at all.